# Restrict text styling options to custom ribbon tab in word document

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, add-in

I have created custom ribbon tab and added the list of text styling options that I want the users to be using inside my document, however I want to **disable all the styling options from the entire document in all the ribbon tabs except the custom tab that I have created**.

[image: Home tab with styling options are disabled]

[image: Custom tab with styling options enabled]

**What I have right now**
All the styling options are disabled across all ribbon tabs.

**What I want**
To disable the styling in all the ribbon tabs **except** the custom one that I've created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing the point. One disables not buttons, but commands. This is the basic idea. You can invoke a command (such as "Font color") from many places, using keyboard shortcuts and so on.

So office allows you to disable a **command**, not a button - and it makes perfect sense.

There is another option - you can remove office ribbon as a whole, using "StartFromScratch" attribute, and provide only the buttons you want instead.